# Alarm Manager: Ignores Alarm Parameters and Runs Method Each Time Activity is Opened

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, persistence, alarmmanager

I am busy with a daily quote app... Alarm Manager is set up to run a method in the MainActivity that populates a listView with a quote from the database each morning at 0900. The method runs and the listView populates just fine but ignores the alarm schedule and the populated data doesn't persist.

If users leaves the main activity then returns, or closes and reopens the app, the method is run again and the list view is populated with a new quote rather than persisting and only running at the scheduled interval.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my code:

Here I register the alarm dynamically in the MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
mTodaysQuoteReceiverStaticInnerClass = new 
TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass();
    IntentFilter filter = new 
IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    this.registerReceiver(mTodaysQuoteReceiverStaticInnerClass, filter);
```

Here is my receiver class (which I made an inner class in the MainActivity):

```
public class TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent){

    MainActivity.this.PopulateTodaysQuote();

    }
}
```

Here is the method that sets my alarm. I call this method from the onCreateMethod in the MainActivity:

```
public void todaysQuoteAlarm(){

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (currentTime <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, 
TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass.class);
            int ALARM1_ID = 10000;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }
        else{
```

Comment: How do you save the data you need to be persistent?

Comment: Normally through saved instance state but I don't think that will work here.

Comment: You need to store it and on on create or on resume check if the service is running and if not start it